# TypeError: Item in ''from list'' not a string for escops

Tags: python-2.7, escpos

I am trying to write a python script ( in window 10 ) that send string data to thermal (ESC/POS) printer. I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) but I couldn't get the sample code to run.

I got "TypeError: Item in ''from list'' not a string" error when I try to run following code

```
   from escpos import *
   Epson = escpos.Escpos(0x04b8,0x0202,0)
   Epson.text("Hello World\n")
```

Can you guys please tell me what's that error code means and how can i fix it? I just started coding python and I have python 2.7.12 and escpos installed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am maintainer of python-escpos. You just found an incorrect passage in the documentation. -_-
I just created an issue on GitHub and this will be fixed asap.

For your question:

You have to instantiate a [USB-Printer](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/printer.html#escpos.printer.Usb). (I am assuming you are using a USB-printer, otherwise please take another one from the list of available printer implementations.) You should get along with [this tutorial](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/usage.html).

The code should then look more or less like this:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb
p = Usb(0x04b8,0x0202)  # these values depend on your printer
p.text("Hello World\n")
```

Comment: @user3570661 has this answered your question? Then would you please be so kind and mark this answer?